# jquery .click() inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

i have a couple of these in my HTML

```
<input id="1" type="button" value="1" >
```

and one

```
<input type="text" name="answer" id="answer">
```

in my js i have

```
sum =(eve)=>{
       dir=$("input:text").val()+eve.target.value;
      $("input:text").val(dir)
     }
      for(let i=1;i<6;i++){
      $("#i").click(sum);
  }
```

why doesn't the click event inside the loop work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#i").click(sum); should be $("#" + i).click(sum);`

You are currently creating event handlers for element with id i, instead you should be creating with id 1, id 2 etc.
My suggestion would be to provide meaningful names.

Answer (score 1):

```js
sum = (eve) => {
  var answer = $("#answer").val() ? parseInt($("#answer").val()) : 0;
  var result = answer + parseInt(eve.target.value);
  $("#answer").val(result)
}

function doSum() {
  for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    $("#" + i).click();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<input id="1" type="button" value="1" onclick="sum(event)">
<input id="2" type="button" value="2" onclick="sum(event)">
<input id="3" type="button" value="3" onclick="sum(event)">
<input id="4" type="button" value="4" onclick="sum(event)">
<input id="5" type="button" value="5" onclick="sum(event)">

<input type="text" name="answer" id="answer">

<button onclick="doSum()">Click to Sum</button>
```